# Check for valid Day hour and Minutes (improve code)

Tags: c#

I have a string in a format like 22 : 19 : 37 where 22 is Days, 19 is hours and 37 is minutes, this is what I have written to validate Hour and Minutes.

```
string value = "22 : 19 : 37";            

string[] time = (value as string).Split(new char[] { ':' });

if (time.Length != 3)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Error");
     return;
}

int DD = System.Convert.ToInt32(time[0]);
int HH = System.Convert.ToInt32(time[1]);
int MM = System.Convert.ToInt32(time[2]);

// Hour should be less than 24
if (HH > 23)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Hour Error");
    return;
}

// Minutes should be less than 60
if (MM > 59)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid Minute Error");
     return;
}
```

I don't like the code, is there anyway to improve this.

Comment: Try parsing as time span

Comment: I think you mean `improve`, not `improvise`

Comment: You don't need `(value as string)` since it's a string already

Comment: Corrected @Jonesopolis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string dateString = "22 : 19 : 37";
string format = "dd : HH : mm";
DateTime result;
var provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

try {
   result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
 Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.TryParse` This I believe is faster and it means you don't have to use try/catches.

e.g:

```
DateTime temp;
if(DateTime.TryParse(yourString, out temp))
//yay
else
// :(
```

Comment: @vivekShukla Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think this will solve the issue, please observe I have a string with Days as it's first component, then followed up by Hour and Minutes.

Answer (score 2):

As this appears to be a TimeSpan rather than a DateTime, here is the variant of @Nkosi. Also using TryParseExact rather than ParseExact. It gets rid of the ugly try catch.

```
string timeSpanString = "22 : 19 : 37";
// For TimeSpan parsing all separator values need to be escaped with \\
string timeSpanFormat = "dd\\ \\:\\ hh\\ \\:\\ mm"; 
TimeSpan result;
var provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeSpanString, timeSpanFormat, provider, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", timeSpanString, result);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", timeSpanString);
}
```

I think this shows the intent more clearly as @Nkosi code will output the data with a year an month.

Comment: I actually used TryParseExact @btlog :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @user3378165. But if cant change your string format you can use a regex expression to check if your string is a valid time string in format HH:MM:SS
A regular expression for this:

```
^\d{2}:([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$
```

Next, use `Regex` object to do the checking